# What is a simple script that can change the data frame name in an MXD?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, data-frame

I've got about 70 MXDs that need the top data frame name (there are multiple data frames within the MXD, I need to adjust the top data frame) changed/replaced.

This is a task that may need to be performed again and again so I want to develop a script that will change the data frame name. For example, change 'Data' to 'Layers'.

Comment: For coding questions please post code that you have tried and note where you are stuck or any errors.   This forum discourages against "do it for me questions".

Answer (score 5):

Using info from [DataFrame](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/dataframe-class.htm#C_GUID-48F7EC9F-155E-4816-BA5D-F7A46E9890FC) - to change data frame 'Data' to 'Layers':

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"c:\temp"
for mxd_file in arcpy.ListFiles(*.mxd):
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_file)
    for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
        if df.name == 'Data':
            df.name = 'Layers'
    mxd.save()
    del mxd
```

Or to modify the name of the top data frame, no matter it's current name:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"c:\temp"
for mxd_file in arcpy.ListFiles(*.mxd):
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_file)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    df.name = 'Layers'
    mxd.save()
    del mxd
```

Comment: Is there a way to point the script to a folder of MXDs?

Comment: @ChristopherHarrod updated to loop through MXDs in a folder